# Busca por semelhança no mongo

Tags: mongodb

Preciso fazer um find no meu mongo por semelhança exemplo

```
[
{
    "nome" : "Erick",
    "codigo" : 1,
    "periodos" : 10
},
{
    "nome" : "Erica",
    "codigo" : 1,
    "periodos" : 10
},
{
    "nome" : "Arthur",
    "codigo" : 2,
    "periodos" : 5
}
]
```

No meu find então vou receber 'eric'

```
cursos.find({
nome: "eric"
}
```

Quero que me retorne os dois elementos que contenham essas String ou seja os dados de Erick e de Erica

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode utilizar [regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/):

`cursos.find({nome: /^Eric/})`

Comment: Passando a String diretamente funciona mas pra mim usar uma variável que contenha a String como faço ? E ainda quero que a busca não seja case Sensitive

Comment: Esse link na resposta contém todas essas informações, se tiver dificuldade de implementar alguma, abra uma nova questão com o código que está a tentar. Boa Sorte.